# Place a billboard at a given distance so that it occupies a certain size on screen

Tags: opengl, matrix-multiplication

I have a rectangle that I place on the screen using a simple scale matrix (`S`). Now I would like to place this rectangle into "3D space", but have it appear just like before on the screen. I found that I can do so by applying the view and projection matrices in inverse. Something like:

```
S' = (V⁻¹ P⁻¹ S)
Matrix = P V (V⁻¹ P⁻¹ S)
```

This works fine so far. My rectangle is like a billboard now and I can treat it like any other object, apply `P` and `V` and it will show up correctly. However, there is a degeneracy here: I don't specify at which depth the object is placed. It could be twice as far away but *x* times bigger!

The reason that this is important is that I want to animate the rectangle, say rotate it around the Z axis or move in 3D space. Then I want it to come to a stop and be positioned pixel-perfect on the screen.

How can I place a flat object *at a given z distance*, such that it appears on screen in a certain way? I already have with the scale matrix that I need to display it in OpenGL without any 3D transformation, that is the matrix for displaying it in NDC or screen coordinates. I also have the projection and view matrices I want to use. How can I go from this to the desired model matrix?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I place a flat object at a given z distance, such that it appears on screen in a certain way [...]

Actually you want to draw the object in view space. Define a model matrix for the object that contains only one translation component *(0, 0, -z)* and skip the view matrix when drawing the object.

Comment: I want to place it in world space because I want to animate it around. But at one point in the animation I want it to be pixel perfect on the screen (like in view space). (Sorry if my terminology is wrong, my 3D graphics skills are rusty :-))

Answer (score 0):

Usually the order to transform 3D vertex v to 2D point p is written as a matrix multiplication. [Depending on the API you are using, the order might be reversed. The notation I used here is glsl - friendly]

```
p = P * V * M * S * v

v = vertex (usually 3D of the form x,y,z,1)
P = projection matrix 
V = view (camera) matrix
M = model matrix (or world transformation)
S is a 4x4 object-scaling matrix 

matrices are usually 4x4 with the last line/column 0,0,0,1
```

The model matrix M can be decomposed into a number of sub components such as T translation, S scale and R rotation. Of course here the order matters.

To rotate an object or vertex around itself, first rotate it (as if it is at the origin already) and then translate it to the position it needs to be, for example using vector v with coordinates (x,y,z).

```
R is a typical 3x3 rotation matrix embedded in a 4x4 with 0,0,0,1 on the last line

v is a 3D vector with coordinates (x,y,z)
T is a 4x4 translation matrix, all zeroes except the last column where it has x,y,z,1 

M = T * R (first R, then T)
```

To rotate an object around an arbitrary point q, first translate it so that it is relative to that point (i.e. q is at the origin, so you subtracted q from v). Then rotate around q (at the origin) by applying R. Lastly place the object it back where it should be (so add q again).

```
R is your typical 3x3 rotation matrix embedded in a 4x4 with 0,0,0,1 on the last line

v is a 3D vector with coordinates (x,y,z)
T is a 4x4 translation matrix, all zeroes except the last column where it has x,y,z,1
L is another 4x4 translation matrix, but now with q instead of v
L' is the inverse transformation of L

M = T * L * R * L'
```

Also, scaling your object first (i.e. S is at the end of the multiplications) before translations will keep the translation in world units. Scale after all transformations, in fact scales all translations too, and the object will move over scaled distances.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I already have the "complete" transformation matrix that makes OpenGL put my texture/rectangle on the screen in the right position. This is just a scaling from texture coordinates to normalized device coordinates. But now I want to place this rectangle with other objects in 3D space - keeping the same visual result. How can I go backwards and calculate the required model matrix? I tried inverting the matrices but this gives an ambiguity wrt. the *z* coordinate of my model.

Comment: Say M = A * B and you know A, you can do A' * M = A'  * A * B. Since I = A' * A, you have calculated B. In your case you don't know the scaling and the position, right? But here you have to make a choice. By fixing the position, you can calculate the scale for that position, or vice versa.